# ¿Como recibir solicitudes con webhooks en node js?

Tags: nodejs, webhook

Hola estoy intentando hacer un bot con node js y este necesita conectarse con otra aplicación mediante webhooks(que no he usado nunca) me he informado buscando en internet pero no consigo encontrar como tengo que hacer para recibir los eventos de los webhooks y como consguir crear un enlace para que me los mande a mi bot. Si alguien pudiese explicarmelo se lo agradecería mucho.

Este es el sitio donde tengo que poner la URL de conexión:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y tengo el bot subido en heroku que no se como puedo hacer para que reciba webhooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El enlace al que tenía que enviar los mensajes de los webhooks en heroku es https://nombre_de_la_aplicacion.herokuapp.com/ y hay que escuchar en el puerto definidio en la variable de configuración PORT y lo demás es como en otros webhooks con express y body-parser he podido recibir los mensajes siguiendo diferentes guias. Al final queda algo así:

```
const authenticationToken = "666";

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000; 

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function(request, response) {

    response.sendStatus(200);

    if (request.headers.authorization === authenticationToken) {
      var webhook = request.body;
      console.log(webhook);
    }
});

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Escuchando");
});
```

Me autorespondo por si alguien en algún momento tiene el mismo problema que lo pueda resolver rapidamente XD o por lo menos más rápido que yo.

Comment: no es la respuesta más elegante, pero sí es 100% el espíritu de un colaborador